# Syntax error, when trying to add value to enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have an enum type `user_trading_style_char`, and it has a few string options, however I'd like to add another one, and came up with this query.

```
ALTER TYPE "user_trading_style_char" ADD VALUE "copy_trader";
```

However it blows up, stating that there's a syntax error at "copy_trader". Not a very helpful error message. Anyone know a way to fix the syntax error or perhaps a better way to add a value to the enum.

Comment: Postgresql documentation uses single quotes. Try single quotes.

Comment: Odd, after changing to single quotes, the syntax error manifests itself at 'user_trading_style_char' now.

Comment: According to docs, this one shouldn't be quoted :)

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Another thing mentioned in the docs is that ALTER TYPE doesn't run in a transaction block, and that's my current error..

Comment: I would use a integer column with [`ActiveRecord::Enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) rather than a native DB enum type. It just works...